# Object initialization similar to List<> syntax

Tags: c#, collections, collection-initializer

How can I define the class so that it could be initialized similarly like `List<T>`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){ //this part };
```

e.g., this scenario:

```
Class aClass = new Class(){ new Student(), new Student()//... };
```

Comment: Does your class inherit from IList?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, to allow [collection-initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax directly on `Class`, it would implement a collection-interface such as `ICollection<Student>`or similar (say by inheriting from `Collection<Student>`).

But *technically* speaking, it only needs to implement the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface and have a compatible `Add` method.

So this would be good enough:

```
using System.Collections;

public class Class : IEnumerable
{
    // This method needn't implement any collection-interface method.
    public void Add(Student student) { ... }  

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { ... }
}
```

Usage:

```
Class aClass = new Class { new Student(), new Student()  };
```

As you might expect, the code generated by the compiler will be similar to:

```
Class temp = new Class();
temp.Add(new Student());
temp.Add(new Student());
Class aClass = temp;
```

For more information, see section "7.6.10.3 Collection initializers" of the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029).

Comment: But nor ICollection and nor IEnumarable have void Add() method, only IList has it.Does it mean that I need to implement IList (is that better practice, although your example works well)?

Comment: `ICollection<T>` does have an [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx) method, although the method that the compiler binds needn't come from that interface (as the example demonstrates). Whether to implement `IList<T>` or not comes down to whether the collection must support  fast access by index.

Answer (score 1):

If you define `MyClass` as a collection of students:

```
public class MyClass : List<Student>
{
}

var aClass = new MyClass{  new Student(), new Student()//... }
```

Alternatively, if your class contains a public collection of `Student`:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public List<Student> Students { get; set;}
}

var aClass = new MyClass{ Students = new List<Student>
                                     { new Student(), new Student()//... }}
```

Which one you select really depends on how you model a class.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anyone suggesting generics implementation so here it is.

```
    class Class<T>  : IEnumerable
{
    private List<T> list;
    public Class()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T d)
    {
        list.Add(d);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

and use:

```
Class<int> s = new Class<int>() {1,2,3,4};
```